# How to use Openpyxl to extract the defined names in Name Manager in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I need to extract all defined names in Name Manager to Python for further analysis. I used the openpyxl package but I didn't find a good way to do that.

I first tried

```
excel_file_path = r"C:\Users\EI34ZU\Desktop\PVW Migration\AD_test.xlsm"
wb = load_workbook(excel_file_path)
namelist = list(wb.defined_names)
```

But for some reason, there are duplicate names with different scopes. So when I printed `namelist`, it eliminated the duplicates for each defined name. Then I saw other people used `wb.defined_names.get()` function, and I tried:

```
print(wb.defined_names.get('Print_Area',scope = wb.sheetnames.index('SW')))
```

where `Print_Area` is the name of the defined constant, and `SW` is the scope. But I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EI34ZU\Desktop\PVW Migration\test\new.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(wb.defined_names.get('Print_Area',scope = wb.sheetnames.index('SW')))
TypeError: DefinedNameDict.get() takes no keyword arguments
```

I guess it is the release version issue?

In addition, the workbook has too many defined names with private scope, so it is kind of impossible to hard code the name one by one.

Finally, it will be perfect if there is some way to access the scope of each name defined, like in a `str`.

Does anyone know how to achieve these? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you check via the name manager in Excel, do the duplicates exist?

Comment: @SolarMike Hi there, yes they do exist. They will have the same name but different scope.

Comment: How can they have the same name? then there is no way to be sure which scope is providing the result, that needs fixing.

Comment: @SolarMike I know this is weird... It supposed to be three Excel files but for some reason people put all the sheets into one, so the Name Manger looks messy, I can't really fix that though... Are there any ways to extract the defined names regardless of the scope?

Comment: Have you looked at the openpyxl documentation?

Comment: @CharlieClark yeah I tried several class functions, but none of them gave desireable results...

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you are working with?